# ADF - replace switch statement for dataflows with a parameterized solution

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I have a switch statement that looks at a variable value and based on that determines which data flow to execute. The problem with this is, I need to update the switch statement every time I add a new ID/dataflow.

Is there an alternative design to this? What if my dataflows had the same name as the variable value - would it be possible to parameterize the name of the dataflow to execute?

e.g. variable value = "1" execute data flow with name "1_dataflow", 2 execute "2_dataflow" etc. How would I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parameterize the values in any activity in Azure Data Factory and make the pipeline dynamic instead of giving hard-coded values.

> You can use parameters to pass external values into pipelines,
> datasets, linked services, and data flows. Once the parameter has been
> passed into the resource, it cannot be changed. By parameterizing
> resources, you can reuse them with different values each time.

You can also use `Set Variable activity` in to define and variable and set value to it which you can use in `Switch activity` and also can change it later.

Refer: [How to use parameters, expressions and functions in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-expression-language-functions), [Set Variable Activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity)